# From a variable how can it be used for dynamically instantiate a class with scope resolution

Tags: php

From a variable how can it be used for dynamically instantiate a class

I want to run something like this

```
$res = Myclassname::create($info);
```

I want `Myclassname` to be set to the actual class name from a variable

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
class abc
{
    public static function def($str)
    {
        echo $str;
    }
}
$a = 'abc';
$a::def('Hello');
```

Comment: My class is in separate file this causes
Uncaught Error: Class 'XXX' not found

Comment: Have you included the class code using php [include](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php).

Comment: Yes its autoloaded. Code works fine with named classes.